# Python Pandas concat or update

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for a function that allows me to concat and update quickly

```
    exchange_name_bid  bids_price  bids_qty
0                 Ftx     18990.0    0.0846
1                 Ftx     18989.0    0.4097
2                 Ftx     18988.0    0.5834
```

and concat with

```
    exchange_name_bid  bids_price  bids_qty
0                 Ftx     18988.0    0.9854
```

If the price already exists I want to replace the quantity and keep the same price and name. And if the price does not exist I want to enter the line and do a normal concat

```
    exchange_name_bid  bids_price  bids_qty
0                 Ftx     18990.0    0.0846
1                 Ftx     18989.0    0.4097
2                 Ftx     18988.0    0.9854
```

else with a new price

```
    exchange_name_bid  bids_price  bids_qty
0                 Ftx     18938.0    0.2354
```

get

```
    exchange_name_bid  bids_price  bids_qty
0                 Ftx     18990.0    0.0846
1                 Ftx     18989.0    0.4097
2                 Ftx     18938.0    0.2354
```

Thanks for help

Comment: If not removed in last dataframe why missing row `2                 Ftx     18988.0    0.9854`  in output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
 df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(['exchange_name_bid','bids_price'], keep='last')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a for to keep the order:

```
for i, row2 in df2.iterrows():
    cond = (df1["exchange_name_bid"] == row2["exchange_name_bid"]) & (df1["bids_price"] == row2["bids_price"])
    if any(cond):
        df1[cond] = row2
    else:
        df1 = df1.append(row2)
```